# What tools should we recommend for participation?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

This question on [which screenshotting tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3578/which-app-can-i-use-for-easily-annotating-pictures-screenshots) reminds me, should we add tool suggestions in the FAQ to encourage better quality questions/answers?

Comment: Great question! I often find myself just using the Gnome Screenshot tool. But being able to add annotations, and other things, would really help in having answers - with screenshots - with annotations!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest at least a mention of <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> (the latter being useful to screenshot a single window rather than the whole desktop).

[image: Screenshot of the default screenshot app... slightly confusing because I have two monitors]

*Screenshot of the default screenshot app... slightly confusing because I have two monitors*

Comment: <Alt>+<Print Screen> is simple and covers 95% of the cases.

Comment: I wish it included the Window borders though...

Comment: Perhaps we should mention alt-printscreen in the "How to ask a question page" so new users can give us a better picture of their problem.